# Is BigDecimal an overkill in some cases?

Tags: java, floating-point, bigdecimal

I'm working with money so I need my results to be accurate but I only need a precision of 2 decimal points (cents). Is BigDecimal needed to guarantee results of multiplication/division are accurate?

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe knowing this exists will help you: http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/CurrencyValidator.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

BigDecimal is a very appropriate type for decimal fraction arithmetic with a known number of digits after the decimal point. You can use an integer type and keep track of the multiplier yourself, but that involves doing in your code work that could be automated.

As well as managing the digits after the decimal point, BigDecimal will also expand the number of stored digits as needed - many business and government financial calculations involve sums too large to store in cents in an int.

I would consider avoiding it only if you need to store a very large array of amounts of money, and are short of memory.

Answer (score 8):

One common option is to do all your calculation with integer or long(the cents value) and then simply add two decimal places when you need to display it.

Similarly, there is a [JODA Money](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/) library that will give you a more full-featured API for money calculations.

Comment: But he wants to do division calculations, which will not be good using an integer where money is concerned

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your application.  One reason to use that level of accuracy is to prevent errors accumulated over many operations from percolating up and causing loss of valuable information.  If you're creating a casual application and/or are only using it for, say, data entry, BigDecimal is very likely overkill.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Patricias answer, but I very strongly discourage anyone to implement own classes with an integer datatype with fixed bitlength *as long* as someone really do not know what you are doing. BigDecimal supports all rounding and precision issues while a long/int has severe problems:

- Unknown number of fraction digits: Trade exchanges/Law/Commerce are varying in their amount
  of fractional digits, so you do not know if your chosen number of digits must be changed and
  adjusted in the future. Worse: There are some things like stock evaluation which need a ridiculous amount of fractional digits. A ship with 1000 metric tons of coal causes e.g.
  4,12 € costs of ice, leading to 0,000412 €/ton.
- Unimplemented operations: It means that people are likely to use floating-point for
  rounding/division or other arithmetic operations, hiding the inexactness and leading to
  all the known problems of floating-point arithmetic.
- Overflow/Underflow: After reaching the maximum amount, adding  an amount results in changing the sign. Long.MAX_VALUE switches to Long.MIN_VALUE. This can easily happen if you are doing fractions like (a*b*c*d)/(e*f) which may perfectly valid results in range of a long, but the intermediate nominator or denominator does *not*.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own `Currency` class, using a `long` to hold the amount.  The class methods would set and get the amount using a `String`.

Division will be a concern no matter whether you use a `long` or a `BigDecimal`.  You have to determine on a case by case basis what you do with fractional cents.  Discard them, round them, or save them (somewhere besides your own account).